# Does flattened objects get automatically updated with @DynamoDBFlattened?

Tags: java, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-java-sdk

I am very new to NoSQL. I am taking a look at `aws-java-sdk-dynamodb` and I found this annotation `@DynamoDBFlattened` that seems to flatten an inner complex object type.

Lets assume the following structure:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Product")
public class Product {

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    private String id;

    @DynamoDBFlattened
    private Supplier supplier;

}

@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Supplier")
public class Supplier {

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    private String id;

    private String name;

}
```

Now let's suppose I have the following supplier on ther **Supplier** database:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Nick"
}
```

And the following product on **Product** database:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "supplier": { "id": "1", "name": "Nick" }
}
```

What happens if I update the supplier on the **Supplier** database to look like this:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "John"
}
```

What happens to the **Product** registry? **Does product with id 1 get its supplier name automatically updated to John? Or it stays Nick?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no relation between the data in the two tables. The purpose of `@DynamoDBFlattened` is to allow you to use complex types in your code that are flattened into individual fields once stored in the DynamoDB table.

In your case specifically, there shouldn't be a `Supplier` table, as the data is stored in the `Product` table. It can only be retrieved through a product unless you use a secondary index to fetch suppliers.